# How do I make :copen use a file instead of makeprg?

Tags: vim

I want to run `make | tee errors.err` and then have `:copen` use `errors.err` to open the quickfix list and jump to any compilation errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `:cfile [errorfile]` instead of `:copen`.

> Read the error file and jump to the first error.